# How to make a image clickable in unity 2d 4.3

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I am developing a 2D game in unity 4.3 i want to know how can we make an image clickable using c#.For example i don't want to use button on game i want different images when user click one of them something happens.like for 'setting' image setting option appears.please tell me how to do this.

Thank you

Comment: Take a tour around google and comeback here when you have an unresouvable bug

Comment: Sir i have tried all links avaliable on google please help if you know how to do this

Comment: No, you didn't. This is the first google result: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/574830/detecting-mouse-click-on-2d-sprite.html

Answer (score 1):

There are one or more way to do this like take sprite as gameobject and get click through script on it,or you can also do this through GUI means OnGUI() method,make your texture variable public and pass your desried image through inspector panel and draw image in OnGUI(),Like

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Texture btnTexture;
    void OnGUI() 
     {
        if (!btnTexture) 
        {
            Debug.LogError("Please assign a texture on the inspector");
            return;
        }
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 10, 50, 50), btnTexture),GUIStyle.None)
            Debug.Log("Clicked the button with an image");

       //Pass Guistyle None so that it behaves like image not a button.

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make a plane in a 3d program or use unity plane ,  texture it with your image  attach a `collider` to it then do a `Raycast`

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create an invisible Button that you put exactly behind your Image.

If you are using the anchor as you are supposed to use it, this is such an easy thing to do.

Then you just add you script to your button. So whenever the "player" will click on your image, your script Button will be executed.